# Solana Anchor: How to make #[account(seeds)] for/ read associated accounts?

Tags: rust, solana

in the Basic-5 tutorial of the  project-serum/anchor repo
How can I replace #[associated]
with something like this:

```
#[account(seeds = [user_data.deposit_last.as_ref(), &[user_data.__nonce]])]
```

There is something not correct above, then Anchor fails to read the associated account's values

```
const userData = await program.account.userData.associated(wallet1, usdcMint);
```

So what is the correct way to replace this soon-to-be-deprecated #[associated] above the associated account struct?

```
#[associated]
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct UserData {
  pub authority: Pubkey,
  pub deposit_last: i64,
  pub shares: u64,
  pub reward_debt: u64,
}

//UserData is initialized here first
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
  #[account(init, associated = authority, with = usdc_mint)]
  pub user_data: ProgramAccount<'info, UserData>,
...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the seed approach is a PDA, which is actually what #associated was using underneath the hood

You will need a function that initializes the seed with the below `init` and `payer` trait. `payer` should also be the same user who is actually paying the for transaction.

Please note that `#[instruction(bump: u8]` is matching the signature of the function here, hence you will need to pass in the bump in the signature as the first argument.

```rs
#[instruction(bump: u8)]
pub struct Ctx<'info> {
  #[account(init, seeds = [user_data.deposit_last.as_ref(), &[bump]], payer = payer)]
  pub user_data = ProgramAccount<'info, UserData>,
}
```

Later on for other functions if you want just want to read the account, you can just use

```rs
#[account(seeds = [user_data.deposit_last.as_ref(), &[user_data.__nonce]])]
pub user_data = ProgramAccount<'info, UserData>,
```

Change your account data to use #[account] instead of #[associated]

```rs
#[account]
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct UserData {
  pub authority: Pubkey,
  pub deposit_last: i64,
  pub shares: u64,
  pub reward_debt: u64,
}
```

Here is an example https://github.com/project-serum/anchor/blob/master/examples/misc/programs/misc/src/context.rs#L10

Comment: yangli-io, thank you! I tried that and I got anchor test working by just replacing #[associated] with #[account], then adding "pub __nonce: u8," to the UserData struct! Is that a shortcut to your function #[instruction(bump: u8] ?

Comment: It's not a shortcut, the `#[instruction(bump: u8)]` is for when you want to be able to access your method parameters

Comment: @yangli-io Your example link gives me a 404 error.  Perhaps it would be helpful to copy the page content into your answer?

Comment: As @RobertOschler mentioned, the example is 404.  This link should last as long as the repo: https://github.com/project-serum/anchor/blob/v0.14.0/examples/misc/programs/misc/src/context.rs